# Not unique table/alias error in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When trying to run I get the error "Not unique table/alias: 'Caller'", im not sure what it means but i feel like it has something to do with joining the same two tables twice on different values

```
SELECT Company_name,Contact_id, COUNT(Company_name) as nc
FROM Customer
JOIN Caller ON Customer.Company_ref = Caller.Company_ref
JOIN Caller ON Customer.Contact_id = Caller.Caller_id
JOIN Issue ON Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id
GROUP by Company_name, Contact_id
HAVING COUNT(Company_name) < 5
```

Comment: Hi. Please google your error message & number without your specific names. And google 'sql unique table' & 'sql unique alias' etc. You are not the first person to get this error. And read the downvote arrow mouseover text & [ask].

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the same table call it another name or both tables to have different names... in this case to avoid confusion let A and B.

```
SELECT Company_name,Contact_id, COUNT(Company_name) as nc
FROM Customer
JOIN Caller A ON Customer.Company_ref = A.Company_ref
JOIN Caller B ON Customer.Contact_id = B.Caller_id
JOIN Issue ON A.Caller_id = B.Caller_id
GROUP by Company_name, Contact_id
HAVING COUNT(Company_name) < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify your column names.  I can guess:

```
SELECT c.Company_name, c.Contact_id, COUNT(*) as nc
FROM Customer JOIN
     Caller co
     ON co.Company_ref = c.Company_ref JOIN
     Caller ca
     ON c.Contact_id = ca.Caller_id JOIN
     Issue i
     ON ca.Caller_id = i.Caller_id
GROUP by c.Company_name, c.Contact_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 5;
```

Whenever you have multiple tables in a query, you should use table aliases and qualified table names.

Without seeing the data, I'm not sure if this does anything useful.  The two joins to the same table on different keys are suspicious.